# What is/are the Arabic word for the God?

Tags: allah, arabic, language

If I translate the word "God" from English to Arabic, it becomes "Allah", because the so called Arabic word for God is Allah. But Allah Himself is the God of Islam, as Islam first refered the word. It's similar to "Jehovah" as Old Testament says the God's name is that.

Is it the only word for the God in Arabic?
If so, then, how the other Pre-Islamic Arab Gods are approached?

What that specific word that can be replaced in Arabic for the word "The God" for a common term?

Comment: The Hebrew word for god is not what you said. The Hebrew word meaning god is "eil"

Comment: ilah is the word you're looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *What that specific word that can be replaced in Arabic for the word "The God" for a common term?*

Allah الله is one of 99 names of God - the almighty, the creator - (SWT).

The correct translation of God is إله. It is written إله but pronounced إلاه (ilaah).

ِAlso آلهة is another possible transition of God.

Example إله:

> وَ**إِلَٰهُكُمْ** **إِلَٰهٌ** وَاحِدٌ ۖ لَّا **إِلَٰهَ** إِلَّا هُوَ الرَّحْمَٰنُ الرَّحِيمُ

سورة البقرة، آية 163

> And your **god** is one **God**. There is no deity [worthy of worship] except Him, the Entirely Merciful, the Especially Merciful.

Surat Al-Baqara, verse 163.

Example آلهة:

> And We made firm their hearts when they stood up and said, "Our **Lord** is the **Lord** of the heavens and the earth. Never will we invoke besides Him any **deity**. We would have certainly spoken, then, an excessive transgression (14) These, our people, have taken besides Him **deities**. Why do they not bring for [worship of] them a clear authority? And who is more unjust than one who invents about Allah a lie?" (15)

Al-Kahf, verses 14 & 15

> وَرَبَطْنَا عَلَىٰ قُلُوبِهِمْ إِذْ قَامُوا فَقَالُوا **رَبُّنَا** **رَبُّ** السَّمَاوَاتِ وَالْأَرْضِ لَن نَّدْعُوَ مِن دُونِهِ **إِلَٰهًا** ۖ لَّقَدْ قُلْنَا إِذًا شَطَطًا (14) هَٰؤُلَاءِ قَوْمُنَا اتَّخَذُوا مِن دُونِهِ **آلِهَةً** ۖ لَّوْلَا يَأْتُونَ عَلَيْهِم بِسُلْطَانٍ بَيِّنٍ ۖ فَمَنْ أَظْلَمُ مِمَّنِ افْتَرَىٰ عَلَى اللَّهِ كَذِبًا (15)

سورة الكهف، آية 14 و 15

Another word is رب which means Lord or Owner. This can be used for human-being, unlike إله, which is only used to refer to God.

> الْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ **رَبِّ** الْعَالَمِينَ

سورة الفاتحة، آية 2

> All praise is due to Allah, **Lord** of the worlds

Al-Faatiha, verse 2

Comment: Omar, pardon me please, that's the Islamic translation "God". What if someone born in Arab, and was in pre-Islamic world, what would he/she says his/her God?

Comment: It's not _Islamic_ it's _Arabic_. The three words I've mentioned in my answer, all refer to _God_. @MayeenulIslam

Comment: Can you please cite some references from Arabic *Torah*, or Arabic *Bible* or any other scriptures that are not Islamic. I'm a Muslim - a practical Muslim, and want to learn from a neutral viewpoint.

Comment: @MayeenulIslam You asked for Arabic translation of the word "God". The Quran verses I have posted are just examples. "_What that specific word that can be replaced in Arabic for the word "The God" for a common term?_"

Comment: *for a common term* - and quoting only Qur'an is not justified - right?

Comment: @mayeenulislam is there a better reference than Quran? :) Not to mention that Quran is Arabic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18932/discussion-between-mayeenul-islam-and-omar).